# C# Доступ к полям объекта

Tags: c#, объекты, доступ

Всем привет!
Есть объект:

```
object data => new
    {
        a = 12128016,
        b = "1",
        c = "1"
    };
```

Мне необходимо привести все это к List string, что пытаюсь сделать:

```
private List<string> res => new List<string>        
    {

    };
```

Но, когда я обращаюсь к объекту data, я не вижу его полей, которые я хочу присвоить в массив res.
Подскажите как быть в данной ситуации.

Comment: Вы используете анонимный тип, зачем? Пишите не `object data`, а `var data` тогда. Либо используйте явный тип, объявите класс.

Comment: В качестве POST запроса отправляю его на сервер

Comment: а при чем тут список тогда? покажите код полностью, где это все происходит. `List<string>` вам практически точно не нужен.

Comment: Вы ж хотели в другом вопросе json посылать для тестирования. Откуда тут у вас появился какой-то список и зачем вам доступ к полям анонимного класса? / `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { A = "kek", B = 555 })` - примерно так, в моём понимании, должно это выглядеть.

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Comment: Да, решил это делать через классы, дело в том, что я отправляю данный объект на сервер, после чего иду в БД смотреть корректность маппинга и чтобы сравнить два этих объекта хотел получить доступ к полям объекта, который я получил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно создать класс (рекомендуется)

```
public class Data
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
}
```

И сделать вот так

```
Data data = new Data
{
    A = 12128016,
    B = "1",
    C = "1"
};
```

---

Можно с анонимным типом вот так

```cs
var data = new
{
    A = 12128016,
    B = "1",
    C = "1"
};
```